# Android webview can't onPause without the app crashing (Need to stop youtube playing in background)

Tags: java, android, webview, google-play, android-webview

I'm making this thread because the answers of similar threads didn't work in my case. I'm trying to publish a simple webview app and some of the pages have embedded youtube videos in them. They keep on playing after the screen is locked on Android 7.0 and below (seems to work fine on android 8) and this is a reason for the app to get rejected. 
I've tried adding network state permission and also utilizing "onPause" as I have seen recommended in other similar threads. If I put in some code that uses onPause (regardless if I use on Resume afterwards or not), the app compiles and the moment it runs on my phone, it disappears a second later (I'm starting to think that maybe the app pauses upon running). Currently, my code is such that I've used onPause without it crashing but maybe not in a right way because the audio keeps on playing. I'm using just android studio, no frameworks.
I've replaced the actual URl with test.com for the purpose of posting here. Here is the code I'm using in MainActivity:

```
 package com.test.moqtasvatba;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Action;
    import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseAppIndex;
    import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseUserActions;
    import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Indexable;
    import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.Actions;
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://www.test.com");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());


    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to handle app links.
    Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();


    }

    /**
    * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    */
    public Action getIndexApiAction() {
    return Actions.newView("Main", "https://www.test.com");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing 
    API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(new 
    Indexable.Builder().setName("Main").setUrl("https://www.test.com").build());
    FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().start(getIndexApiAction());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().end(getIndexApiAction());
    super.onStop();
    }


    WebView webView; // Initialize this somewhere

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    if(webView != null){
    webView.onPause();
    webView.pauseTimers();
    }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(webView != null){
    webView.onResume();
    webView.resumeTimers();
    }
    }

    }
```

Activity main file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">



<WebView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/webView"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.moqtasvatba">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses- 
permission>
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="15"
android:targetSdkVersion="26" />


<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

<data
android:scheme="https"
android:host="www.test.com" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

I would very much appreciate some advice on how to properly use onPause and where to put it exactly so that the app doesn't stop right after opening.

Comment: Could you post logcat when your app is opened

Comment: @Michal_196 With the code above, the onpause method seems to now work at all so the app doesn't crash. I assume you would like the logcat of when the app crashes so you can see the reason. Here is a link to a pastebin containing the logcat and also the java code in MainActivity.java that is used in the scenario. [link](https://pastebin.com/j6tSYJhQ)

Comment: According to log, line 27 is causing the crash, see it